# What are the standard file extension of files generated by llvm tool chain?

Tags: clang, llvm

I have the following code and commands.

```
==> main.c <==
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include <stdio.h>

void print();
int main() {
    print();
    return 0;
}

==> print.c <==
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include <stdio.h>

void print() {
    puts("Hello World!");
}
$ clang -c -emit-llvm -o main.bc main.c
$ clang -c -emit-llvm -o print.bc print.c
$ llvm-link -o main1.bc  main.bc print.bc
$ lli main1.bc 
Hello World!
```

However, I am not sure what are the widely accepted file extensions should be.

I have `main1.bc`and `main.bc`, both have `.bc` extension. However, `main1.bc` can run with lli and was generated by llvm-link. So it is probably better to distingish it with `main.bc` and `print.bc`.

Could anybody let me know the generally accepted standard of file extensions and the recommended commandline workflow? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `llvm-link` tool operates on LLVM bitcode and outputs the same bitcode, so there is no difference between `main.bc` and `print.bc`.

Canonical extensions for textual LLVM IR - `.ll`, compiled one - `.bc`.